# Regular expression in ASP.NET for validator

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I want regular expression in asp.net validator for below:

```
2012T8
```

1. first must be valid year up to now
2. second must be character T
3. third must be any single digit

Can anyone help?

Comment: what have you attempted so far?

Comment: HELLO ericosg, till now I'm upto this ^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}$ but I don't think this would be preferable solution, as per my requirements...

Comment: I work on it and come upto this ^(19|20)\d{2}(Q|q)[1-4]{1}$ with this first must be year between 1900-2099 then Q or q and then any digit between 1-4.But still I want year value properly. Which I can't manage.

Answer (score 0):

I usually avoid regex as if not all my team members are familiar with it, our code seems gibberish and easily solvable bugs are missed, so we usually just code the match.

Naturally regex is blaziongly fast and if you're matching against a lot of data, it's the best way to go.

I think what you need is this:

```
^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3}[T][0-9]{1}$
```

The {1} dictates the amount of characters that must meet the match, so it's 1 character for a number > 0, then 3 characters being any number, then the letter T then a single number.